# Authorise the localhost in ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-2.2

I am newbie in ASP.NET Core, and I have a controller  that I need to authorise only in my machine, for test purposes, but deny on others...

I have the following config:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_2);
    services.AddMvc().AddJsonOptions(options =>
    {
        options.SerializerSettings.DateFormatString= "yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ssZ";
    });
    services.AddAuthentication("Cookie")
        .AddScheme<CookieAuthenticationOptions, CookieAuthenticationHandler>("Cookie", null);
    services.AddLogging(builder => { builder.AddSerilog(dispose: true); });
```

And on the test controller I enabled the `[Authorize]` attribute:

```
[Authorize]
public class OrderController : Controller
```

Is there a way to allow my local machine to be autorised to access the controller's actions? Something like `[Authorize(Allow=localhost)]`

Comment: That's no authorization, it's an IP restriction. Unless you mean "I want to allow this already authenticated user to call `OrderController` only if the connection comes from this IP". That's possible too by using the IP as another claim. Authorization means checking whether a user has permission to do something. Authentication is actually finding out who the user is.

Comment: I need that an identified user, and user from my machine only (localhost) to be authorised to perform the controller's action.

Comment: This is available and explained in the docs [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/ip-safelist?view=aspnetcore-3.1). The config setting in the examples is even called `SafeAdminList`

Answer (score 3):

You can create an action filter like so:

```c#
public class LocalhostAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext context)
    {
        var ip = context.HttpContext.Connection.RemoteIpAddress;
        if (!IPAddress.IsLoopback(ip)) {
            context.Result = new UnauthorizedResult();
            return;
        }
        base.OnActionExecuting(context);
    }
}
```

And then use the tag `Localhost`:

```c#
//[Authorize]
[Localhost]
public class OrderController : Controller
```

I believe this will work, restricting the access to the machine where it's executed.

Comment: it works (code 202) only if the `[Authorize]` is commented out... of not I get 401

Comment: @Serge, glad I could help, as Panagiotis Kanavos commented `Authorize`is for user access, so in theory it shoud work if user is authenticated, try to test it out, you can also use it in specific controller methods.

Answer (score 1):

This is more whitelisting than authorization. Authorization means checking whether a user has permission to do something. To do that, the user must be identified first, ie authenticated.

The article [Client IP Safelist](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/ip-safelist?view=aspnetcore-3.1) in the docs shows how you can implement IP safelists through middleware, an action filter or a Razor Pages filter.

**App-wide Middleware**

The middleware option applies to the entire application. The sample code retrieves the request's endpoint IP, checks it against a list of safe IDs and allows the call to proceed only if it comes from a "safe" list. Otherwise it returns a predetermined error code, in this case 401:

```
public async Task Invoke(HttpContext context)
{
    if (context.Request.Method != "GET")
    {
        var remoteIp = context.Connection.RemoteIpAddress;
        _logger.LogDebug("Request from Remote IP address: {RemoteIp}", remoteIp);

        string[] ip = _adminSafeList.Split(';');

        var bytes = remoteIp.GetAddressBytes();
        var badIp = true;
        foreach (var address in ip)
        {
            var testIp = IPAddress.Parse(address);
            if(testIp.GetAddressBytes().SequenceEqual(bytes))
            {
                badIp = false;
                break;
            }
        }

        if(badIp)
        {
            _logger.LogInformation(
                "Forbidden Request from Remote IP address: {RemoteIp}", remoteIp);
            context.Response.StatusCode = 401;
            return;
        }
    }

    await _next.Invoke(context);
}
```

The article shows registering it before `UseMvc()` which means the request will be rejected before reaching the MVC middleware :

```
app.UseMiddleware<AdminSafeListMiddleware>(Configuration["AdminSafeList"]);
app.UseMvc();
```

This way we don't waste CPU time routing and processing a request that's going to be rejected anyway. The middleware option is a good choice for implementing a *black*list too.

**Action Filter**

The filtering code is essentially the same, this time defined in a class derived from ActionFilterAttribute. The filter is defined as a scoped service :

```
services.AddScoped<ClientIpCheckFilter>();

services.AddMvc(options =>
{
    options.Filters.Add
        (new ClientIpCheckPageFilter
            (_loggerFactory, Configuration));
}).SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1);
```

In this case the request will reach the MVC infrastructure before it's accepted or rejected.

**Razor Pages Filter**

The code is once more the same, this time deriving from IPageFilter

Comment: these methods does not seem to work with the "Authorize" attribute on the controller... The action on localhost is denyied 401 if the authorize is present...